# Can the default (yellow) highlight color be altered in Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-addons

I'd like to know if there's a way to modify the (yellow) color that Gmail uses to highlight the message text found as a result of a search.

I reviewed the Gmail API but didn't see anything relevant.  I'd like to know if this is something that can be done using a Chrome extension instead.

Comment: Inspect it in devtools and find the selector. Then simply override it in your content script CSS file.

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thanks for that.  I found the selector, then used a Chrome extension named Resource Override that injects the new CSS into any page (I'm asking it to match https://mail.google.com//*).  It works great.   Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.